# How can I put multiple paths into the same domain in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I want to connect `domain.com/c` to `/var/www/a/c` and `domain.com/b` to `/var/www/b`. And I wrote nginx sites-available file like following:

```
server {
    listen 443 ...

    index index.php index.html;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www/a;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /b {
        root /var/www/b;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

But I see 404 when I enter `domain.com/b`. I tried using `alias` instead of `root` but I got the same result. How can I do?

Comment: can u provide the logs of nginx?

Comment: 404 page appears. There is no error in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` uses your global `root /var/www/a;`. Here are just two possible solution among many others:

1. Use the nested PHP handler:

   ```
   server {
       listen 443 ...

       index index.php index.html;
       server_name domain.com;
       root /var/www/a;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

       location ^~ /b/ {
           root /var/www;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /b/index.php?$query_string;
           location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
           }
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
       }
   }
   ```

   Or if your `/var/www/b` is the only PHP app, your can just add a `root` directive to your PHP handler:

   ```
   server {
       listen 443 ...

       index index.php index.html;
       server_name domain.com;
       root /var/www/a;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

       location /b/ {
           root /var/www;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /b/index.php?$query_string;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
           root /var/www;
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the `map` directive to get your web root from the request URI:

   ```
   map $uri $root {
       ~^/b/    /var/www;
       default  /war/www/a;
   }
   server {
       listen 443 ...

       index index.php index.html;
       server_name domain.com;
       root $root;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

       location /b/ {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /b/index.php?$query_string;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried, but there was a 500 error and the log has the following message. `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/b/index.php"` When I created another server with `b.domain.com`, I used the same `root`, `try_files`, but this error did not appear...

Comment: There were two copy-paste errors (`location ^~ /b/ { ... }` instead of `location /b/ { ...}`), please try now.

Comment: Is your `/b/` URI prefix equals that `/var/www/b` folder name?

Comment: The two are different. I think I should change the folder name to `/var/www/sampleb`.

Comment: You should have mentioned it in your question. Of course none of the above configurations will work in this case. And you can't use `try_files` and `alias` directives together due to [this](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) nginx long-standing bug. The most simple simple solution to you will be renaming that `/var/www/b` directory according to your URI prefix.